# How to make Thread paused or stopped when view disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, nsoperation

How to make Thread paused or stopped when view dispear i do that:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];    

     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];
}
```

but didnt work

Comment: Why do you want this?? It's not good practice to pause a thread.

Comment: As already stated several times, you really really really shouldn't be doing this. What exactly are you trying to achieve? We may be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: I have two viewcontroller, in the first view i display images from database and if the user click button bar to pass in the second view i want to stop the thread in the first view and when the user comeback in the first the thread continuous

Comment: don't sleep thread, its not food habit .. just disable your button...

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in `viewWillDisappear` but more likely you probably shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should never sleep for longer than a few milliseconds in the UI thread.  If you do the OS will kill your application, in addition to it behaving poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you button disable instead of NSThread sleep

```
[yourBtn setEnabled:NO];
```

When you retrieve complete data then enable it

```
[yourBtn setEnabled:YES]
```